# MDCTextField How do i resolve those deprecated class warnings?

Tags: ios, swift, material-ui

Working on textfield with floating labels with the help of MaterialComponent pod.Textfield class showing warning like MDCTextField' is deprecated: MDCTextField and its associated classes are deprecated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvo3R.png)

Please use TextControls instead.Can any one help me how i can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning you are seeing in the IDE is telling you to use TextControls instead of MDCTextField.
If you go to Material UI's [documentation](https://m2.material.io/components/text-fields/ios#filled-text-field), you can see that you need to follow these steps to use TextControls:

1. Add the relevant pods to your Podfile (your screenshot doesn't show much in respect to what components you are using):

   ```
   pod 'MaterialComponents/TextControls+FilledTextAreas'

   pod 'MaterialComponents/TextControls+FilledTextFields'

   pod 'MaterialComponents/TextControls+OutlinedTextAreas'

   pod 'MaterialComponents/TextControls+OutlinedTextFields'
   ```
2. Run `pod install`
3. In the class you want to use the UI component, add the relevant imports:

   ```
   import MaterialComponents.MaterialTextControls_FilledTextAreas

   import MaterialComponents.MaterialTextControls_FilledTextFields

   import MaterialComponents.MaterialTextControls_OutlinedTextAreas

   import MaterialComponents.MaterialTextControls_OutlinedTextFields
   ```
4. Use the component of your choice (an example of a FilledTextField):

   ```
   let textField = MDCFilledTextField(frame: estimatedFrame)

   textField.label.text = "Phone number"

   textField.placeholder = "555-555-5555"

   textField.leadingAssistiveLabel.text = "This is helper text"

   textField.sizeToFit()

   view.addSubview(textField)
   ```

For other examples, you can head over to the documentation linked above.